# Shop with Ajax Filters and Load More Functionality Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, e-commerce

I am working on a shop page with ajax filter and load more functionality , as of Load more working perfect when no there is no filter applied , same filters are working good but when I click on load more it bit becomes buggy when I remove filters it shows no data .

Load more button :

```
<button id="load-btn" type="submit">
<span>Load more</span>
</button>
```

Load More Clicked function:

```
var page = 1;
   var clicked = false
   $("#load-btn").click( function(e) {
        page++;
        clicked=true;
        filter();
      }
     );
```

Ajax Request :

```
 function filter() {
          var url = '{{ route("front.shop.filter") }}';
                var categories = [];

          $(".category:checked").each(function(){

            categories.push($(this).val());
            console.log(categories)
            
        });
              
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: {
                       categories:categories,
                       page: page
                      },
                    type: 'post',
                    beforeSend:function(){
                      $('.load-more').show(); // loader
                      
                      if(!clicked){
                         $('#products').html('');
                        
                      }
                    }
                }).done(function(data){
                   setTimeout(function(){ 
                      $('.load-more-skelton').hide();
                      if(clicked == 1){
                         $('#product').append(data.view);
                         clicked = false;
                          page = 1;
                      } else {
                         $('#product').html(data.view);
                      }
                   
                   }, 1500);
            
                });
       }
```

SearchController

```
public function filters(Request $request)
    {

        $products = Product::where('status' , 'active');

       
        if($request->categories){
            $products = $products->whereIn('category_id',$request->categories);
        } 

        $products = $products->latest()->paginate(8);

       
        $view = view('front.includes.view',compact('products'))->render();
        

        return response()->json(['view' => $view]); 
    }
```

Can anyone assist me in implementing the load more functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

This will be faster since you wont be getting all the Products from DB :

```
$query = Product::query();
$query->where('status' , 'active')->latest();
if ($request->categories) {
    $query->whereIn('category_id', $request->categories);
}
$products = $query->paginate(8);
```

Comment: Hi @Doğuş since this is filteration so there will be another options as well for user to filter so how can I save those in $products variable ?

Comment: Hi @Dogus thanks one part of the problem is solved means when I apply filter and click on load more it is getting the data correctly , but when I remove filter after using load more button previously then it is showing no result found .

Comment: Can you comment the pagination line then return '[$query->toSql(),$query->getBindings()]' instead of what you are returning so we see the raw sql and bindings

Comment: Hye @Dogus nothing is changed when I put $products = [$query->toSql(),$query->getBindings()]; instead of $products = $products->latest()->paginate(8);